# Why does nginx proxy_pass to a variable only pass the root url

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to implement this suggestion to make my nginx service start even if the upstream service isn't there https://sandro-keil.de/blog/let-nginx-start-if-upstream-host-is-unavailable-or-down/

I've removed other locations for simplicity

gitea is the name of the service on the stack i am proxying to

So with this configuration everything works ok

```
    server {
        # resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s; ## internal docker dns
        #listen   [::]:3011 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        listen 80;
        client_header_timeout 120s;
                client_body_timeout 120s;
                client_max_body_size 200m;

        # save logs here

        server_name sigyl.com;


        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }


    server {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=30s; ## internal docker dns
        #listen   [::]:3011 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        # listen 444
        listen 443 ssl;
                # this should allow large docs
        client_header_timeout 120s;
                client_body_timeout 120s;
                client_max_body_size 0;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/sigyl.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sigyl.com/privkey.pem;
        # save logs here
        #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;


        # Recommendations from https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        # required to avoid HTTP 411: see Issue #1486 (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1486)
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;

        server_name sigyl.com;


        location /git/ {
           proxy_pass http://gitea:3000/;
        }

  }
```

however if I set a variable like this:

```
   .....     
        location /git/ {
           set $upstream http://gitea:3000/;
           proxy_pass $upstream;
        }

  }
```

all the requests just return the root url

ie

https://example.com/git/vendor/plugins/jquery.areyousure/jquery.are-you-sure.js

just returns what's at https://example.com/git/

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam's comment here explains the problem

https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p/973311#comment1306507_593003

so I ended up with:

```
location ~ /git/(.*) {
  resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=30s; ## internal docker dns set
  $upstream http://gitea:3000/$1$is_args$args;
  proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```